# How to add standard message errors to custom validator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code:

```
  validate  :food_types_cannot_be_nil

  def food_types_cannot_be_nil
    if food_types.blank?
      errors.add(:food_types, 'cannot be nil')
    end
  end
```

But now I want that instead of 'cannot be nil' text of message will be standard text for blank objects (validates presence). Can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
validates_presence_of :food_types, :message => "Whatever message you want"
```

If you want default message then don't give any message here. It will automatically take default one

Comment: As you can see I use custom validator. Can 'validates_presence_of' check for blank?

Comment: Yes, its obviously for blank value. For your reference you can refer [rails help](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_presence_of)

Answer (score 0):

See docs for [ActiveModel::Errors#add](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of)

The second parameter `kind` can be a String for any custom error message, or a Symbol for a standard error message.

In your case,

```rb
  validate  :food_types_cannot_be_nil

  def food_types_cannot_be_nil
    if food_types.blank?
      errors.add(:food_types, :blank)
    end
  end
```